# Why is NLog not working from Controller.OnException?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nlog

I have NLog set up correctly and I know it is reading the config file.

I have a test controller action:

```
    public JsonResult Exception()
    {
        throw new Exception("This is a test exception thrown from TestsController.  It should be logged and displayed in an error page from BaseController.OnException().");
    }

    public JsonResult Logging()
    {
        Log.Info("Logging test called from TestsController");
        Log.Error("Logging test called from TestsController");
        return Json("Called Log.Info and Log.Error.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I also have logging in my BaseController.

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }

        var e = filterContext.Exception;
        Log.Error(e, "BaseController.OnException caught exception: ");

        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(e, controllerName, actionName);

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
        };
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
```

This all works perfectly when I am running my system in "DEV"/localhost.

When I publish the ASP.NET MVC project to my test server, all of the logging works **except for the logging in the OnException Method**.  The OnException method works otherwise by displaying the error view. Why?

I am logging to a DB and I can manually run the INSERT statement in DEV and TEST without any issues. My test system is deployed to an IIS virtual directory.

As to why I am using `OnException`, that is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the issue for me.  Don't register the **HandleErrorAttribute**.

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        // Logging was not working.  Remove HandleErrorAttribute.  Allows OnException to work.
        // filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new UpstreamAuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```